# Localization in Xamarin Android C#

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm working on an app in which I have to give support for multiple languages on a button click. Is it possible to have this functionality ?

Please suggest how?

Comment: on android you could use @android:string/ values

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for a button click that switsches to English. You han do with other languages the same way:

```
   _btnen= FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnEN);
        _btnen.Click += delegate
        {
            //string _sprache = "EN";
            Java.Util.Locale.Default = new Locale("en", "GB");
            Resources.Configuration.Locale = Java.Util.Locale.Default;
            Resources.UpdateConfiguration(Resources.Configuration, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
            Finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, this.Class);
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
```

Comment: I'm using similar code but its not changing the language from english to chinese

Comment: have you added the string resources for your language to your app resources folder?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution this code actually works for me!!

> Android.Content.Res.Configuration conf = this.Resources.Configuration;

if (conf.Locale.Language == "en")

{

```
            var languageIso = language;

  var locale = new Java.Util.Locale(languageIso);// languageIso is locale string

            Java.Util.Locale.Default = locale;

      var config = new Android.Content.Res.Configuration { Locale = locale };

     this.Activity.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(config this.Activity.Resources.DisplayMetrics);

            //SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainActivity);

            this.Activity.Recreate();


        }
```